# Xamarin and SQLite: fix a corrupt database and shrink

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.forms

is there a way to shrink a database from the code? I found in my database some tables are corrupted: how is it possible to detect that from code and fix it?

When I try to update a record in a particular table with a `Execute`, I receive always a `Corrupt` error.

The definition of the table is

```
[Table("tbl_Colour")]
public class Colour : BaseTableListing {
}

public class BaseTableListing : ITableEntity
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    [Indexed]
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = "";

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    // more fields
    // ...
}
```

The query is

```
UPDATE tbl_Colour SET IsUpdated = 0, 
SynchronizeDate=CAST((((JulianDay('2017-04-04 09:22:12', 'localtime') 
    - 2440587.5)*86400.0) + 62135596800) * 10000000 AS BIGINT) 
WHERE ID = 57;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is this where `database` if your database in your solution or project:

```
/// <summary>
/// Compacts the database.
/// </summary>
public void CompactDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        SQLiteCommand cmd = database.CreateCommand("vacuum");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("CompactDatabase has an error: " + ex.Message);

        // if you use MobileCenter
        Analytics.TrackEvent("CompactDb Error", new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "Message", ex.Message },
            { "Source", ex.Source },
            { "StackTrace", ex.StackTrace.ToString() }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, vacuum is a normal command and you can execute it as every command. I think it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The command to shrink a sqlite file is **VACUUM**:
https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html

It rebuilds the file, so maybe it could solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your message

Comment: I found another command `integrity_check` but I don't know how I can call it from a `CreateCommand`